# Session ID always changing - can't login to my web application from ONE PC!!! Sessions being lost!

Tags: php, session

we've recently done some installation but I'm facing issues with one pc in particular and its baffling. We have a webapplication installed on our local server which is accessed by all our workstations. FOr some reason we can't log into our webapplication using one workstation. The application is a PHP MYSQL collaboration system. I double checked and for some really odd reason whenever we login it creates a session ID but upon logging in and redirecting to another page the session is broken and a new session id is generated thus the individual is automatically logged out again.

What could be the issue here - is its a firewall thing - its not the web application as we can access it fine via the other workstations. We even disabled the firewall but in all cases that single dumb workstation seems to have an issue with maintaining the session.

Help please - I'm sure its an issue confined to that one PC - what could it be.

#### Update

The authentication sequence is as follows:

1. Login
2. Authenticate user
3. Build session
4. Store session variables with session ID in db
5. Redirect
6. `SESSION` variables are empty - a new session ID is generated
7. Since new session ID is not of an authenticated user - return to login

#### More details

- SSL is not enabled
- Cookies are enabled are on the problem machine

### UPDATE

I don't understand how can redirection be the problem here. My redirection code is as follows I'm using the following function to redirect to the index page upon successful login.

```
function _redirect($url)
{   
    #To redirect to a specified page
    if(headers_sent())
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=$url\">";
    else
        header("Location:$url");
    exit; 
}
```

Plus even if it is an issue why is it a problem on just one PC and not on the others? I don't wish to change my code just to accommodate one system as opposed to fixing whats wrong with that one system which is preventing it from behaving in the first place.

## MORE UPDATE

I just double checked and found something odd. My login is ajax based i.e. a request is made via ajax if it is a success the session variables are generated and a boolean 1 is sent back upon receiving  the user is redirected via a javascript call which is:

```
function _redirect(url)
{
 window.location = url;
}
```

I commented out this call and instead when the user is logged in I manually go to the index page and it works fine!! What is the javascript redirect messing up in this one pc thats not messing up in the other workstations is beyond me :( How do I fix this?

Comment: Without browser version information and a network traffic log, this question isn't really actionable.

There's basically no question that there's a cookie issue on the machine in question.

Comment: Something like the Live HTTP Headers plugin for firefox might be handy. If you are not using it already. I find it handy for debugging these kinds of problems.  

 https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/

Answer (score 0):

what browser are you using on this workstation? IE? Firefox? Have you tried different web browsers? Tried checking the browser settings yet? What is the time out set to? Is the time on the server and workstartion syncing properly with ntp?

In IE you can disable accepting of sessions cookies if the security is set to high I believe.

Comment: I've used all browsers and its the same issue.The timeout has been set to well real long - so thats not an issue. I can access it fine from all other workstations save one!

Answer (score 0):

If you're losing the session, it's likely because the session cookie is not being transmitted. Does the browser on that machine have cookies enabled? Are you using SSL for your login page? Does your login code do anything besides validate a username/password (e.g. validate an IP address or machine name)?

#### Edit

Can you verify with Fiddler/Wireshark that the session cookie is transmitted when you redirect? Can we see some example login code?

Comment: NO SSL - cookies are enabled - my login script takes the user credentials logs in and stores the session id in a database as well as maintain session. However upon redirection the session is destroyed and I lose all my variables once I am redirected!

Comment: Most browsers let you turn on warnings when you receive a cookie.  A good way to verify that it actually happens (without blocking it).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the cookie is not being set and sent back to the server properly on this machine.  Verify that you have cookies enabled and that you don't have some 3rd party browser extension or other software blocking cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the question to begin with (hence my edit history)

What is the domain the login is on and the main site is on? If it's between domains (could be anything like sending between example.com and www.example.com)

Comment: I didnt understand how is the redirection causing issues?

Comment: Both are in the same domain. they're in the same root folder. The index.php file just has one function call which checks to make sure if someone is logged in. If not it redirects him back to login.